# How to serve / from a static file, but the rest of the root directory from a proxy (NodeJS)?

Tags: nginx, proxy, node.js

I've tried the following:

```
    # this *should* serve the root from a static index.html file
    location = / {
            try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # resources are served directly by nginx
    location /img {
    }
    location /css {
    }

    # all other URLs are served dynamically by nodejs
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    }
```

The `location /img`, `location /css` and `location /` clauses work.

I'm having trouble with `location = /`.  I added `$uri $uri.html $uri/` because `tryfiles` won't accept just `/index.html` as a single argument.

Requests to `/` are passed upstream, rather than being answered by nginx serving the (static) index.html file.

How can I redirect the root directory to the proxy server (NodeJS), while serving a literal '/' from a static file?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by another method:

```
    # any url that is not served by a file is passed to nodejs
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @backend;
    }

    # all other URLs are served dynamically by nodejs
    location @backend {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    }
```

Comment: This is a much better configuration. It serves static files and only goes to your backend if there is no static file.